# Read data from binary file into linked list in C (Access violation reading location )

Tags: c, linked-list

**Edited the code, now I have a problem with reading from the file. My struct doesn't get the values.**

It feels like I'm going mad, I'm trying to find a solution for this for like 8 hours... so here is my structure

```
typedef struct _megye
{ 
    int megye;
    int hektar1_min;
    int hektar1_max;
    int hektar1_tam;
    int hektar2_min;
    int hektar2_max;
    int hektar2_tam;
    int hektar3_min;
    int hektar3_tam;
    struct _megye *next;
}megye;
```

Well, it is trying to be a linked list. Here is how I tried to read data from my file and put it in the struct:

```
{
    FILE *fb;
    megye*p;
    megye *mhead;
    mhead=(megye*)malloc(sizeof(megye));
    p=mhead;
    fb=fopen("tamogatas.dat", "rb");

    if (fread(p, 3, 7, fb) != 7)
    {
        printf("there was an error");
    }
    else
    {
        p=p->next;
        p=(megye*)malloc(sizeof(megye));
        p->next=NULL;
    }
    fclose(fb);
    return 0;
}
```

By the way my file looks like this:

> 1 50 100 2 100 200 4 200 6

7 rows of this kind.

So if I run this then I get the error "Acces violation reading location". Please help me what to do, in class we haven't do anything like this, but they still want it.

Comment: what does p=p->next=malloc try to do?

Comment: It allocates memory for the next element of my list. Isn't it the right way to do that?

Comment: you are doing p=p->next=(megye*)malloc(sizeof(megye));
    p->next=NULL;   so, first p=p->next, erase the actual p, then p->next=malloc, allocate the next element, and in the next line p->next=NULL, lose the allocated memory pointer by assigning NULL to it

Comment: It looks like you're trying to read 7 megye-sized chunks from the file and store them into space allocated for 1 megye.

Comment: Actually yeah, it seems like the problem is with the reading of the file. The debugger of VS2013 shows that random numbers are in my structure's ints.

Comment: also maybe sizeof(megye) != one record size of file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appear to be several problems here.

One:

```
FILE *fb;
megye*p;
mhead=p=(megye*)malloc(sizeof(megye));

fb=fopen("tamogatas.dat", "rb");

if (fread(p, sizeof(megye), 7, fb) != 7)
```

I would recommend that you avoid the a = b = c ... syntax.  It can lead to subtle bugs and is easy to miss when reading.  However the real problem is what exactly you are expecting fread to do here.  Is your data file in binary?  If not you will not get what you expect.  If it is you are expecting it to read all 7 binary struct values and store them in a memory location allocated for only one such struct.  This is almost certainly not what you want to do.

```
{
    printf("there was an error");
}
else
{
    p=p->next=(megye*)malloc(sizeof(megye));
    p->next=NULL;
}
fclose(fb);
return 0;
```

In your else clause you are allocating another struct location and setting both p and p->next equal to that location.  Then you set p->next equal to NULL.  Again this is almost certainly not what you want to do.

To form a linked list you need a head which points to either NULL (empty list) or another node.  Each node has a next field that points to either NULL (end of list) or the next node in the list.  Each node should be allocated separately and each read should read only that node (in the correct format).  I'm guessing your input file is in text so you will need to convert each number to a binary value.  One way to do this is by using the standard fscanf(...) function.

Comment: Well, I was a bit misleading. My file is actually a binary file, I just showed a line from the source txt file which I converted to binary from. 

I see what you are saying about linked lists, I'm going to fix it now.

Comment: I don't agree on your comment about the p->next allocation. I fully agree with you on the awful a = b = c syntax. However even if this is kind of bad, p = p->next = malloc should work anyway. It first allocates the next element, then it makes p to point to it, `mhead` holding the head of the list. (But don't do that even if it works, this is confusing)

Comment: I don't disagree, I just don't see the point of setting p->next then in the next line setting p->next to NULL.

Answer (score 1):

I see two major categories of problems with the code as presented.

## Pointers and Lists

This clause

```
    p=p->next;
    p=(megye*)malloc(sizeof(megye));
    p->next=NULL;
```

is either causing your access violation, or is going to cause further problems down the road.

A linked list is a sequence of nodes, where each node points to the next node in the list. Implementing a linked list requires understanding pointers. The three lines I quote above show a deep misunderstanding of pointers.

A pointer is simply the address of something. Here, `p` is the address of some node, and `p->next` is a field in that node containing either `NULL` or the address of the next node in the list.

Once you execute the line `p = p->next` you have forgotten the address of the previous node, so you can no longer modify its `next` field. The subsequent assignment to `p` only modifies the variable `p` itself, and not the `next` field of the previous value of `p`.

A correct way to express the addition of a new node to follow the node currently pointed at by `p` is this:

```
    p->next = (megye*)malloc(sizeof(megye));
    p = p->next;
    p->next = NULL;
```

If you want to be pedantic about error detection, then also check to see that `malloc()` actually returned a non-NULL value. You can eliminate the third line by using `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`, which will also have the advantage of initializing all the fields of the `struct` to all 0 bits, which is required by the C standard to be the same as the numeric value 0, 0.0, or a NULL pointer.

## File IO

You defined a `struct megye` apparently to be the node structure of a linked list (it contains a `next` field that is a pointer to that struct), then used one as the destination for `fread()`.

The call to [`fread()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fread) will read bytes from the file, and put them in memory at the buffer you requested. Its arguments are the address of the buffer to fill, the size of an array element, the count of elements, and the `FILE *` from which to read.

You wrote:

```
    if (fread(p, 3, 7, fb) != 7)
```

which is asking to read seven copies of 3-byte structure into memory pointed at by `p`, which was earlier initialized to the the pointer to the head node of your list. Your list node is not 3 bytes in size. it has 9 `int` fields and a pointer, and on a common 32-bit architecture is likely to be 40 bytes total.

As a result, the 21 bytes you read from the file (7 3 byte elements) does not overflow the allocation. However, it also does not line up with any portion of the structure.

If you really have a binary file with 3-byte integers, then you need to introduce some code that reads the file and translates the format.

Even if you intend to hold natural sized integers, separating the file format from the internal representation is a good idea. Once you try to exchange this data with a different architecture system, you will see the benefit. Different machines can have different values for `sizeof(int)`, and even if the size is the same, different platforms store the individual bytes of the `int` in different orders.

Another problem is that since you mention having seven rows of data in the file, you might be attempting to read in the entire list in a single operation. That will not work as you expect. Even if you have a valid linked list in memory, you cannot simply write it to a file because the pointers will be addresses that are valid in this particular running instance of the program, and cannot be written to a file and read back safely.

For more on these file I/O and data representation issues, look into the broad topic of "serialization". This is not a simple problem.

For learning purposes, I would strongly recommend serialization into simple text files so that you can see what you got in a text editor, and build simple test cases by hand.

Answer (score 0):

First, you may want to be careful about fopen looking if it successfully opened your file by checking the value of fb, before trying to read its content.

Then, from what I see, you allocated size for only 1 of your node (sizeof megye) but with your fread call, you try to set 7 * sizeof(megye) bytes at `p` address.

Another problem is the structure itself, as you keep the data and the pointer to the next node of your list in the same structure, that is morever filled from a file. It means, you will set an arbitrary address to next from your file. Is your file containing bytes for the next field as well?

I suggest to split your struct. One struct for the data, the other one for the list. Then, it will be much easier to fill only the data part of the struct.

Finally, if this works, you don't need to cast malloc result. The implicit cast works just well and is much more readable.